# Multi-factor Authentication for Windows login

Tags: c#, windows, two-factor-authentication

I'm searching for a documentation for multi-factor authentication for Windows AD Logon.

Scenario: A user logs in on their computer/RDP-session and after pressing ENTER, they are interrupted by another field to enter a PIN-code. (Something like: http://youtu.be/_q8FbRb64As)

I've been searching for two hours now and all I can find are methods for ASP.NET and ADFS.

Comment: What version of windows and AD?

Comment: Currently I'd like to have this on Windows Server 2008 and 2012.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the thing to do when wanting to implement two (or multi) factor authentication on current versions of Windows is to implement a credential provider. Both SMS Passcode (who created the video the OP linked to) and Duo Security seem to do that.

Information on creating a credential provider can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648647(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying! If available, do you know any example code pieces? I know it sounds lazy but I didn't expect to read that a lot of information, haha.